# What type of wood does black oyster mushrooms grow on?

Tags: mushrooms, growing-medium

I have a bag of black oyster mushroom sawdust, and was wondering what type of wood I should use to make [totems](http://tadmontgomery.com/2012/10/14/oyster-mushroom-cultivation/) with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dark Oyster mushroom (Pleurotus sp.) having a place with Class Basidiomycetes and Family Agaricaceae is famously known as 'dhingri' in India and develops normally in the mild and Most regularly found on deciduous hardwoods and tropical woodlands on dead and decaying wooden logs (trees that lose their leaves). Beech and aspen trees are normal. Sometimes found on conifers also.

Comment: The “missing lines” were not lost but intentionally removed. The reference to the supplier did in no way add or link to additional information regarding the question and is therefore considered undisclosed advertising (aka spam). I am giving you the benefit of the doubt here and keep the remaining answer. This also concerns your other post.